# Using cleveref with 2 different styles

Tags: graphics, hyperref, subcaption, cleveref

I like to style my `\cref` as following (Geophysical Prospecting):

Type 1: Fig. 1, Fig. 1(a), Fig. 1(a,b), Figs 1 and 2

Type 2: (Fig. 1), (Fig. 1a), (Fig. 1a,b), (Figs 1 and 2)

I have tried with `\creflabelformat`, `\crefname`, and `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}`. But it will not give me the option to call two types of labelling with `\cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\caption{Sub: a}\label{sub:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\caption{Sub: b}\label{sub:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CAPTION TEXT.}\label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}\caption{CAPTION TEXT 2.}\label{fig:Test2}\end{figure}
\textbf{I want:}\\ Fig.~1, Fig.~1(a), Fig.~1(a,b), Figs~1 and 2. (Fig.~1), (Fig.~1a), (Fig.~1a,b), (Figs~1 and 2).\vspace{1em}

\textbf{I get:}\\ \cref{fig:Test}, \cref{sub:a}, \cref{sub:a,sub:b}, \cref{fig:Test,fig:Test2}. \Cref{fig:Test}, \Cref{sub:a}, \Cref{sub:a,sub:b}, \Cref{fig:Test,fig:Test2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first issue is that `\cref{sub:a,sub:b}` uses the `conjunction` format, which is by default set to ` and `. This can be cured with `\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{,}`, the parentheses however require more work